# chrome <input type="date" not working properly

Tags: google-chrome, html-input

Am using  in my page.I want to close the calender pop up once user chosen the date.Now its not happening that way. after chosen the date, user need to click some other places of the web page to close the pop up.then only it getting close.I don't know this is default functionality of chrome or not.So please any one suggest me that how to close the pop up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: right now am using google Version 27.0.1453.94 m..Actually it was working till last week..whether they updated.

Comment: If you think this behavior change is a bug, let's file a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the spec there doesn't seem to be any standard for the date control UI.  I personally am not a huge fan of Chrome's date input UI; I think they need to improve it quite a bit, but they are the only browser that actually provides a UI at all.

Rather than depend on this UI, use `<input type=text>` and use JS to provide a custom UI for date selection that will be consistent across browsers and fulfill your own needs.